# Python mysql replication - Missing Data

Tags: python, mysql, replication

Dear Developers/community

I am using mysql replication library to stream my aws RDS binlogs to redshift. Everything is working fine except one thing, I am not getting some records from a table.
After investigating, I came to know that data in this table is being populated a very high frequency and during that time, I am not getting some of the records

Please note that I am reading binlogs of a slave server. This is replica of my production. Point here is changes of this table are propagating to all slaves perfectly. I am not sure why python is not reading some of changes.

Here is my pyton code snippet

```
stream = BinLogStreamReader(
connection_settings={
"host": SRC_DB_HOST,
"port": src_db_port,
"user": user_bi,
"passwd": user_bi_pwd},
server_id=227336,
blocking=True,
resume_stream=True,
ignored_tables=ignored_tables_list,
log_file=log_file, log_pos=log_pos,
only_events=[WriteRowsEvent, UpdateRowsEvent, DeleteRowsEvent])

for binlogevent in stream:
     ##creating local file with records
```

ignored_tables_list: this contains some tables to exclude

There are no invalid characters in my missing records. They are same as others.

Please help

Comment: Were you able to identify this issue, I am planning on implementing a similar one our system and i want to fully aware of any issues that we could face.